# On dataquest, there is a "for app in apps_data" - what does the for app do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
opened_file = open('AppleStore.csv')
from csv import reader
read_file = reader(opened_file)
apps_data = list(read_file)

for app in apps_data[1:]:
    price = float(app[4])
```

I know that when we did for row in apps_data, I thought that Python understood what row is hence it performed the function for us. How does it know what "app" is?

And if we added it ourselves, where did we define it.

This is related to the dataquest course.

Answer (score 0):

When you do :

```
for app in apps_data[1:]:
    price = float(app[4])
```

`app` is a new name (you don't have to use it first). The for loop makes sure that app takes each value from `apps_data[1:]` in turn.

That is the point of a for loop - you are selecting each item one at a time.

The full definition can be summarised as :

```
for <target> in <iterable>:
```

Here  is one or more names, and they take the value(s) in turn from

In your case  == `app` and the iterable is apps_data[1:]